# Angular geocoding results not synchronous

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use a google geocoding as a [POC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_concept) for a feature that I might be working on, however I'm having issues.

Basically it starts with user typing their address in search input, the geocoding service returns the address list, because different addresses can happen in different locations or if the user misspelled, so the user can select a right one.

So first step the search (angular controller) :

```
$scope.submit = function(addressform) {
      $scope.addresses = geocoder.getAddressList($scope.formData.address);
}
```

Geocoder is a internal factory that uses google map, and google geocoder. This is a relevant geocoder code to this example:

```
app.factory('geocoder', function(GoogleMap) {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(),
  return {
    getAddressList: function(address) {
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          return results;
        } else {
          alert("Couldn't find that address! Google Maps says: " + status);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

This is the view part :

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat='address in addresses'>
    <a ng-click='displayOnMap()'>{{address.place_id}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This should write the geocoding results into the view. The issue I'm having is that the controller which invokes geocoder method executs returns immediately, but some time after that the geocoder actually returns results.

How do I make angular controller wait until geocoder actually invokes the return statement and returns results, so I can update my html then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be able to escape the fact that `geocoder.geocode` is asynchronous.

You have a couple  options: The first would be to pass in a callback to `getAddressList` and call the callback on success. A more angulary way would be to use the [$q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

```
getAddressList: function(address) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      deferred.resolve(results);
    } else {
      deferred.reject("Couldn't find that address! Google Maps says: " + status);
    }
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Controller will need changing too:

```
$scope.submit = function(addressform) {
  geocoder.getAddressList($scope.formData.address).then(function(result) {
    $scope.addresses = result;
  }, function(err) {
    alert(err);
  });
}
```

Don't make alert calls from a service. It's a UI concern.

Comment: thanks for the response that worked. As I m starting out with angular I realized my first version of this wasn't angular way of doing things, I did it with jQuery when geocoder returned results I'd append list to the html. I think this is the way to do it, however I'm not sure what you mean by "Don't make alert calls from a service. It's a UI concern.", where should I make the call from?Should I have a UI concern of some kind or? thanks

Comment: It was just a comment on your original code. Things that interact with the UI should stay out of services. Notice how in my revised code I kept the `alert` out of the service. The service just returns a message. How that message is used in the UI (if at all) is a concern of the controller, not the service.

Comment: ah thanks I understand now. Indeed the service does return a message, it's not worried about displaying it via alert or any other UI interface, it's job is to deliver the gecoding results. How the results are displayed on the page, that part is on the html side, so I guess I did what you recommended. Thanks again!